# How many edges can a networkx graph approx. hold? Does adding edge attribute increase the memory needed to created such a graph?

Tags: networkx

I am working on creating a networkx graph using a dataset containing over 200 000 data items. The nodes are integers. I am facing memory error issue while adding edges. I had done something similar last week and there was no memory issue. I can only assume that the no. of edges getting added in my current code has increased due to the different problem statement. What can be done regarding memory error?

Comment: what sort of attributes dothe edges have?

Comment: just the weight attribute. float32 data type